# While let chain causing rust-analyzer to complain about the feature being unstable in Rust 1.66, wasn't this just merged into stable recently?

Tags: rust

```
    while let Some(peek_ch) = chars.peek() && peek_ch.is_whitespace() {
      chars.next();
    }
```

The above code is causing rust to complain with

```
`let` expressions in this position are unstable
see issue #53667 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/53667> for more information
```

My understanding was if-let and while-let chaining was stabilized? Also, from this error and github issue I can't determine what unstable feature to enable to allow this, how do you normally determine that?

Comment: It's complaining about the `&&`. The error message is a bit wrong..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're not allowed to use `&&` with `while let` yet because unfortunately the merge of the stabilization [had to be reverted](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/100538)

If you use a nightly compiler it will tell you what feature you have to enable to make it work:

```
> cargo +nightly run
...
error[E0658]: `let` expressions in this position are unstable
 --> src/main.rs:4:11
  |
4 |     while let Some(peek_ch) = chars.peek() && peek_ch.is_whitespace() {
  |           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: see issue #53667 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/53667> for more information
  = help: add `#![feature(let_chains)]` to the crate attributes to enable
```

So this works with nightly rust:

```rust
#![feature(let_chains)]
fn main() {
    let mut chars = "hello".chars().peekable();
    while let Some(peek_ch) = chars.peek() && peek_ch.is_whitespace() {
        chars.next();
    }
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a9c3ad45149530ab13309ee26f7a14ce)

Or you can work around it with one of PeterHalls stable solutions.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the `&&`, not the `while let`. As written, you are trying to match the result of the expression `chars.peek() && peek_ch.is_whitespace()`, but this doesn't make sense because `peek` returns an `Option<T>` while `is_whitespace` returns a `bool`.

The error message is a little bit misleading because it thinks you are trying to use `if let` *chains*, an unstable feature which allows you to match on multiple patterns.

You can rewrite this with:

```
while let Some(peek_ch) = chars.peek() {
    if peek_ch.is_whitespace() {
        chars.next();
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

Or

```
while let Some(peek_ch) = chars.peek().filter(|c| c.is_whitespace()) {
    chars.next();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Peter, I was intending to use if let chains and my understanding was that this feature had been made stable in recent versions of Rust but I was mistaken. I accepted the other answer because I did intend to do it this way and will be enabling this unstable feature rather than using the stable solutions you provided.

Comment: Oh, I have been looking at older versions of that RFC. The feature is a bit different now it seems.